# How make wsimport (JAX WS) with no secure SSL

Tags: java, ssl, jax-ws, wsimport

I need to implement the JAX WS client.
Unfortunately, I have problems because of the SSL certificate.

```
C:\jaxws-ri\bin>wsimport -keep -verbose -XdisableSSLHostnameVerification   -extension -p ewulka https://test-interm
```

this line gives me output:

> [ERROR] sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to fi
>   nd valid certification path to requested target
>
> Failed to read the WSDL document: https://test?wsdl, because 1) could not find the document; 2) the
>   document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .
>
> [ERROR] Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s):
>
> At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.

```
    Failed to parse the WSDL.
```

What should I change here?

Comment: This would mean that the certificates of the (web-service)host you are trying to connect are missing in your trust-store.

Comment: I try to test old webservice from downloaded localhost. I have one test in Soap UI which is working :). But i want to make JUnit test with JAX-WS client.